# Change a jQuery UI Dropdown's background color depending on Checkbox status

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, selector

I'm using [jQuery UI SelectMenu](http://bit.ly/nBxRGR) and [jQuery UI Custom Checkboxes and Radio Buttons](http://bit.ly/qQIKmn) to style a form on a page. In setting up the form, I define my dropdown as such:

```
$('select#em_basic_life_plans').selectmenu({
    style:'dropdown',
    width: 378,
    maxHeight: 238
});
```

And create the dropdown within the page like so:

```
<fieldset>
    <select name="em_basic_life_plans" id="em_basic_life_plans" tabindex="10" />
    <option value="" selected="" class="selectmenu-req-format">Plan: select</option>
    <option value="5K">Plan: 5K Flat Benefit</option>
    <option value="10K">Plan: 10K Flat Benefit</option>
    <option value="100K Maximum">Plan: 100K Maximum</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

Because there are some dropdowns (like the one above) which are required, I style them with a light yellow background and dark yellow text so that the user knows they are required (optional dropdowns have a light grey background and grey text). I do this by declaring a background color different from the light grey default set in my SelectMenu CSS and by also applying a separate class to the text like so:

```
#em_basic_life_plans-button {background-color: #fff4bf !important;}
```

and, written into the option itself (as seen above):

```
class="selectmenu-req-format"
```

Hopefully that sets things up. Now for my question:

**How do I change the background color of the above dropdown from light yellow back to light grey, depending on when a certain checkbox on the page is unchecked?**

**I thought that this would work:**

```
$('#basic_cov_life').click(function() {
    if ($('#basic_cov_life').is(':checked')) {
        alert("Debugging: this is now checked.");
    }
    else {
        $('#em_basic_life_plans-button').css('background-color:#B3B3B3;');
    }
});
```

The code for determining whether or not the checkbox (#basic_cov_life) is checked is working... it's just the code to change the color back to grey that isn't working:

```
$('#em_basic_life_plans-button').css('background-color:#B3B3B3;');
```

Any ideas on what to do to change the background color back to light grey? And also, though I haven't gotten to it yet with the above code, I would need the text to change back to grey as well.

Thanks so much in advance for any insight!

Berklie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `click` handler `this` will point to the checkbox you clicked so you don't have to use `$('#basic_cov_life')`. To set any css style `css` method takes 2 arguments(property/value) or a map. Try this.

```
$('#basic_cov_life').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#em_basic_life_plans-button').css('backgroundColor', '#fff4bf');//Set the appropriate color here
    }
    else {
        $('#em_basic_life_plans-button').css('backgroundColor', '#B3B3B3');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the use of `this`... however, neither what I had `$('#em_basic_life_plans-button').css('background-color:#B3B3B3;');` nor what you suggested  `$('#em_basic_life_plans-button').css('backgroundColor', '#B3B3B3');` are changing the background color. Anything else that you can think of? Thanks again.

Comment: `$('#em_basic_life_plans-button').css('backgroundColor', '#B3B3B3');` definitely works. Can you check `$('#em_basic_life_plans-button').length`? Are you sure you have the right selector id?

Comment: Hi there. Yep, dropping `alert($('#em_basic_life_plans-button').length);` gives me a value of "1" each time that I click the checkbox... so I know that I've got the correct Selector ID. I think it's getting complicated due to the fact that within the SelectMenu CSS I am declaring it as light grey, and then I'm using `#em_basic_life_plans-button {background-color: #fff4bf !important;}` when the page loads. So, I'm left not being able to work with it as clear cut as `$('#em_basic_life_plans-button').css('backgroundColor', '#B3B3B3');` should allow. Might I need to override `!important` somehow?

Comment: Can you remove important from the css. Change it to '#em_basic_life_plans-button {background-color: #fff4bf;}. If that do not work then try to pass `!important` in the css method along with the color, like this `$('#em_basic_life_plans-button').css('backgroundColor', '#B3B3B3 !important');

Comment: You know, we had `!important` declared so that IE6 would behave. However, now that we no longer support IE6, I can actually remove `!important`. Removing `!important` (with quick testing in IE8, Firefox, Safari, and Chrome) accomplishes our desired "required" color change to light yellow (and proves it is no longer necessary to us). So, without having `!important` in the top declaration... your code now works as expected. Apparently, `!important` really means no override. Thank you much! What other code can I use to change the text color to grey from yellow (`class="selectmenu-req-format"
`)?

Comment: To change the text color use `css("color", "specifyColorhere")`.

Comment: You know, I have a better idea... and I hope that you can help, Shankar. How can I change the class of a certain option, instead of using `"color"` to change all of the options' text colors. I would like to make this option's class `<option value="" selected="" class="selectmenu-req-format">Plan: select</option>` go over to this class `selectmenu-opt-format` when the checkbox is checked. Ideas on how to apply the class change to only that option? Thanks!

Comment: Try this `$('select#em_basic_life_plans option:selected').css("color", "specifyColorHere")`

Comment: Aww, that didn't work. Thank you, though. Since I will only ever want to change the very first option of the dropdown (option "0") from `class="selectmenu-req-format"` to `class="selectmenu-opt-format"`... is there a way to have the first option ("0") change class, instead of specifying a color? See you.

Comment: `$('select#em_basic_life_plans option:first').addClass("className")`

Comment: Aww, this `$('select#em_basic_life_plans option:first').addClass("selectmenu-opt-format");` didn't work, either. But, I've taken up too much of your time, so I'll keep trying other code. Thanks so much for everything today! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("basic_cov_life").checked // returning boolean
```

or

```
$("#basic_cov_life").attr("checked") // returning attribute value
```

or

```
$("#basic_cov_life").prop("checked") // returning attribute value
```

Comment: I appreciate the code, but it's the background color changing bit which needs help. I've got the checkbox's checked/unchecked determination working.